# Invoke background process using angular js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

How can i invoke stored procedure which is long running (approx 3 mins) using asp.net MVC + Angularjs.

Explanation - there is table of records in UI, each record will have process button which will trigger the the background process or call the stored procedure to do the background activity. how can be done using asp.net mvc + angualrjs in non-blocking way?

Comment: Use ajax calls (angular's `$http`), which are async so they will not be blocking the UI

Comment: Break the pen on paper to understand how to use services in Angularjs, and use WebAPI rather than MVC controllers to do the database manipulations.

Comment: @devqon - yes, i am able to invoke the background process. Thanks!!